# What is $^C in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand this code in Perl that I have inherited:

```
sub myfunc($)
{
    my ($path) = @_;
    unless ($^C)
    {
        # manipulate path
    }
    return $path;
}
```

But I do not understand the `$^C` test.  What does it do?

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EC

Comment: The current value of the flag associated with the -c switch.
Thanks!

Comment: perldoc -v '$^C'

Answer (score 6):

Perl's `-c` switch compiles the source and tells you if the syntax is valid. However, Perl doesn't have a strict separation between compile-time and run-time. You can run some code during the compilation (`BEGIN` blocks), and you can compile code when you are running (`eval()`).

This means that you might think that you are safe while syntax checking, and that you would be wrong. The second example actually runs some code:

```
$ perl -c -le 'print "Hello!"'
-e syntax OK

$ perl -c -le 'BEGIN{print "Hello!"}'
Hello!
-e syntax OK
```

This is more important in IDEs. Many of these will continually run `perl -c` on your source so it can highlight problems. However, this also means that your IDE is now potentially a trojan horse for executing that code you just copied and pasted from Stackoverflow.

Thus, the `$^C` guard (see [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)):

```
$ perl -c -le 'BEGIN{ print "Hello!" unless $^C }'
-e syntax OK
```

I'm guessing that the developer who put that there either had a bet to use all the special variables in one program, or was reacting to unwanted behavior from their tools.